# Setting a div to not influence scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have quite an annoying problem, for which I don't seem to be able to find an easy fix. Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <!-- Some HTML here -->
        <div id="menu"><!-- Some stuff here --></div>
        <!-- Some HTML here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#page {
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 2000px;
    margin-left: -2000px;
}
```

This would give a centered page div, with a menu bar in there. Thing is, whenever the browser width becomes > 1200px, the div will not grow any further, but the menu div must at all times stretch all the way to the window edges. And the problem with this approach now is, that I get a horizontal scrollbar because the menubar is bigger than the screen. So, I am looking for a solution for this. Something that disables the scrollbar from having impact on the horizontal scrollbar would do. Disabling the horizontal scrollbar isn't an option however, since the content must be scrollable on small devices as well...

I am aware that I could fix this by pulling the menu bar outside of the page div, but that is hard, since I am editing a Drupal theme and I want this change to have as little impact as possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is that you want the div to stay 100% width all the way but to have scrolling inside of it? If so then you should have a wider div inside the main div.
Something like this-

```
<div id="full-width">
    <div id="scrolling-div">
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #full-width {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        overflow-x:visible;
    }

    #scrolling-div {
        float:left;
        width:300%;
        height:500px;
    }
</style>
```

I tested this code, it works :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, scrolling inside the menu div is never necessary. Also, the full width div should be centered and I would prefer the full-width div not to be set to an absolute positioning, since this screws up the existing layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy fix this by setting your html and body styling like this:

```
html, body {
   overflow-x:hidden;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

This should do it with the current code you have now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but like I mention in my post, horizontal scrolling should not be disabled altogether.

Comment: I don't get your question then, you could just use media queries when coming down to a specific width then and remove the overflow again.

The code answer i just posted will not disable the scrollbar for the content, the content can still be scrollable - But not extend to over the window with.

Comment: Won't work, since whenever the horizontal scrollbar becomes available, it will scroll too far, because of the insane padding that I add. That is also the case for small window widths. And the design uses the window scrollbar, no div scrollbars for scrolling content, so I really need this window scrollbar, but I would just like the menu div to have no influence on this window scrollbar at all. But I guess this is difficult.